# Order categories by count in a countplot

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, bar-chart, countplot

I know that [`seaborn.countplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html) has the attribute `order` which can be set to determine the order of the categories. But what I would like to do is have the categories be in order of descending count. I know that I can accomplish this by computing the count manually (using a `groupby` operation on the original dataframe, etc.) but I am wondering if this functionality exists with `seaborn.countplot`.

Answer (score 187, accepted):

This functionality is not built into [`seaborn.countplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html) as far as I know -  the `order` parameter only accepts a list of strings for the categories, and leaves the ordering logic to the user.

This is not hard to do with [`value_counts()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) provided you have a DataFrame though. For example,

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.set(style='darkgrid')

titanic = sns.load_dataset('titanic')
sns.countplot(x = 'class',
              data = titanic,
              order = titanic['class'].value_counts().index)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: What if I'd like to order ascending?

Comment: @dax90 Call `.value_counts(ascending=True)` in there.

Comment: How to sort it by the x label?

Comment: orientation is switched by changing x= to y=

Answer (score 12):

Most often, a seaborn countplot is not really necessary. Just plot with pandas bar plot:

```
import seaborn as sns; sns.set(style='darkgrid')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = sns.load_dataset('titanic')

df['class'].value_counts().plot(kind="bar")

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

`sns.countplot` is a special bar-plot that computes group-wise count under the hood. So another way to order categories by count is to plot the `value_counts()` result instead.

```py
s = df['class'].value_counts()
s = df['class'].value_counts().rename_axis('class').rename('count') # if x- and y-labels are important
sns.barplot(x=s.index, y=s.values, order=s.index)
```

[image: img]

---

Another example where the bars are sorted in ascending order of counts.

```py
s = df['class'].value_counts(ascending=True)           # compute counts by class
ax = sns.barplot(x=s.index, y=s.values, order=s.index) # plot count plot
ax.set(xlabel='class', yticks=[], title='Number of survivors by class', frame_on=False) # prettify
ax.tick_params(length=0)                               # remove tick liens
ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0]);                        # add bar labels
```

[image: img2]