# Seaborn.countplot : order categories by count, also by category?

Tags: python, pandas, plot, seaborn

So I understand how to sort in regards to a barchart (ie [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46623583/seaborn-countplot-order-categories-by-count)). What I can not find though is how to sort the bar charts by one of the subcategories.

For example, given the following dataframe, I can get the bar plots. But what I would like to do, is have it sorted from greatest to least, by `Type` of `Classic`).

```
import pandas as pd

test_df = pd.DataFrame([
['Jake',    38, 'MW',   'Classic'],
['John',    38,'NW',    'Classic'],
['Sam', 34, 'SE',   'Classic'],
['Sam', 22, 'E' ,'Classic'],
['Joe', 43, 'ESE2', 'Classic'],
['Joe', 34, 'MTN2', 'Classic'],
['Joe', 38, 'MTN2', 'Classic'],
['Scott',   38, 'ESE2', 'Classic'],
['Chris',   34, 'SSE1', 'Classic'],
['Joe', 43, 'S1',   'New'],
['Paul',    34, 'NE2',  'New'],
['Joe', 38, 'MC1',  'New'],
['Joe', 34, 'NE2',  'New'],
['Nick',    38, 'MC1',  'New'],
['Al',  38, 'SSE1', 'New'],
['Al',  34, 'ME',   'New'],
['Al',  34, 'MC1',  'New'],
['Joe', 43, 'S1',   'New']], columns = ['Name','Code_A','Code_B','Type'])


import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="darkgrid")
palette ={"Classic":"#FF9999","New":"#99CC99"}


g = sns.countplot(y="Name",
                  palette=palette,
                  hue="Type",
                  data=test_df)
```

So instead of:

[image]

'Joe' would be on top, followed by 'Sam', etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the `order` argument. Use `pandas.crosstab` and `sort_values` to obtain this:

```
import pandas as pd

test_df = pd.DataFrame([
['Jake',    38, 'MW',   'Classic'],
['John',    38,'NW',    'Classic'],
['Sam', 34, 'SE',   'Classic'],
['Sam', 22, 'E' ,'Classic'],
['Joe', 43, 'ESE2', 'Classic'],
['Joe', 34, 'MTN2', 'Classic'],
['Joe', 38, 'MTN2', 'Classic'],
['Scott',   38, 'ESE2', 'Classic'],
['Chris',   34, 'SSE1', 'Classic'],
['Joe', 43, 'S1',   'New'],
['Paul',    34, 'NE2',  'New'],
['Joe', 38, 'MC1',  'New'],
['Joe', 34, 'NE2',  'New'],
['Nick',    38, 'MC1',  'New'],
['Al',  38, 'SSE1', 'New'],
['Doug',    34, 'ME',   'New'],
['Fred',    34, 'MC1',  'New'],
['Joe', 43, 'S1',   'New']], columns = ['Name','Code_A','Code_B','Type'])


import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="darkgrid")
palette ={"Classic":"#FF9999","New":"#99CC99"}

order = pd.crosstab(test_df.Name, test_df.Type).sort_values('Classic', ascending=False).index
g = sns.countplot(y="Name",
                  palette=palette,
                  hue="Type",
                  data=test_df,
                  order=order
                 )
```

[image]

Comment: oh geez. I was thinking it was much more complicated. Ok. Got it.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer as it's exactly what I was looking for. But just curious, this will sort then by 'Classic'. What if I wanted it to sort by 'New' first (I adjusted the test data above)

Comment: Updated my answer actually, misread the part about it being order by count of 'Classic'

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

test_df = pd.DataFrame([
['Jake',    38, 'MW',   'Classic'],
['John',    38,'NW',    'Classic'],
['Sam', 34, 'SE',   'Classic'],
['Sam', 22, 'E' ,'Classic'],
['Joe', 43, 'ESE2', 'Classic'],
['Joe', 34, 'MTN2', 'Classic'],
['Joe', 38, 'MTN2', 'Classic'],
['Scott',   38, 'ESE2', 'Classic'],
['Chris',   34, 'SSE1', 'Classic'],
['Joe', 43, 'S1',   'New'],
['Paul',    34, 'NE2',  'New'],
['Joe', 38, 'MC1',  'New'],
['Joe', 34, 'NE2',  'New'],
['Nick',    38, 'MC1',  'New'],
['Al',  38, 'SSE1', 'New'],
['Al',  34, 'ME',   'New'],
['Al',  34, 'MC1',  'New'],
['Joe', 43, 'S1',   'New']], columns = ['Name','Code_A','Code_B','Type'])


import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="darkgrid")
palette ={"Classic":"#FF9999","New":"#99CC99"}

sb.countplot(y = 'Name', hue='Type', data=test_df, 
order=test_df['Name'].value_counts().index)
```

[image: Output]